# Convirtiendo archivos a JSON para consolidarlos en Python

Tags: python, json, bucle-for

Estoy haciendo un script que ingresa a una carpeta y realiza un FOR por todos los archivos de dicha carpeta, copia los datos que yo necesito, arma un json por cada archivo y luego los unifica a todos en un JSON General que lo uso para una base de datos.

La primera parte esta hecha, el problema esta en que no entiendo como ingresar a los datos del for sin tener que entrar por un IF, dejo un ejemplo.

```
for filename in os.listdir(carpeta):
    if filename.endswith(".chr"):
        archivo = open(os.path.join(carpeta, filename), 'r', encoding="ANSI")
        lectura = archivo.readlines()

        for linea in lectura:
            if "=" in linea:
                clave, valor = linea.strip().split("=")

                # Cuenta

                if clave == "Cuenta":
                    dict1["Nombre"] = filename.replace(".chr","").capitalize()

                # Cuenta


                # Nivel
                if clave == "ELV":
                    dict1["Nivel"] = int(valor.strip())
                # Nivel
```

Esta parte funciona bien, puedo obtener el dato "ELV" porque entro en un IF que cuando este pasando por esa linea me guarde en el dict1 la información que necesito.

Bueno, ahora es cuando necesito sumar dos valores del archivo original, estos valores son 'NeuMatados' y 'CiudMatados'

este es mi codigo

```
                # KD
                if clave == "NeuMatados":
                    NeuMatados = int(valor.strip())
                elif clave == "CiudMatados":
                    Ciudadanos = int(valor.strip())
                # KD

                print(NeuMatados + Ciudadanos)
```

Cuando quiero hacer eso, me dice que las funciones no están definidas (NeuMatados y Ciudadanos) ¿Como puedo hacer para acceder al valor de la clave que yo quiero?

intente con print(clave["NeuMatados"]) pero me dice que no puedo usar un STR, que tengo que usar un INT (como si tuviera que hacer un slice, pero no es la idea)

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a la comunidad.

El error te dice que no tienes definidas las variables NeuMatados y Ciudadanos porque:

Si tu código **no** ingresara en el if  `if clave == "NeuMatados":` tal vez porque no existe esa palabra en algún archivo, entonces la variable NeuMatados nunca se crearía y eso te arrojaría error en el `print(NeuMatados + Ciudadanos)`.

**Como solucionarlo:**

Simplemente declara e inicializa las variables fuera del if así:

```
            NeuMatados,Ciudadanos = 0,0

            # KD
            if clave == "NeuMatados":
                NeuMatados = int(valor.strip())
            elif clave == "CiudMatados":
                Ciudadanos = int(valor.strip())
            # KD

            print(NeuMatados + Ciudadanos)
```

Además, cuando hagas esto `print(clave["NeuMatados"])` debes tener en cuenta que no puedes imprimir un entero como un número sino que debes hacerlo con string. Por ello debes convertirlo así:

```
print(str(clave["NeuMatados"]))
```